# Conocer el número de registros de una base de datos desde PHP

Tags: php, mysql

Para saber el número de registros que tiene una base de datos, y usar este valor para iterar por ejemplo, suelo usar éste método:

```
$statement = $conexion->prepare("SELECT * FROM info_XboxOne ORDER BY agregado DESC");
$statement->execute();
$todos_juegos_xbox_one = $statement->fetchAll();

$total = count($todos_juegos_xbox_one);
```

Después con la variable `$total` ya podría iterar. El problema que me estoy encontrando es que la tabla de la base de datos es tan grande que me da el siguiente error:

> Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 134217728 bytes exhausted (tried
>   to allocate 32 bytes) in
>   /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/xboxone/index.php on line 15

¿Hay alguna otra forma de obtener el tamaño de la tabla?

Comment: Tu problema es que traes todos esos registros a memoria para, luego, contarlos. Puedes cambiar la consulta SQL, utilizando la función `COUNT(*)` . Dicha función te devolverá directamente el número de filas de la consulta, sin necesidad de traer todos esos resultados a memoria.
**EDIT**: Deberías añadir a tu pregunta si tu interés es recorrer dichos campos, o solo "*conocer el número de registros*", como dices en el título. Si tu interés es el primero, deberías tener en cuenta que la consulta devuelve demasiados resultados.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Si lo que deseas es saber el número de registros que tiene la tabla **info_XboxOne** lo que debes hacer es usar COUNT(*), de la siguiente forma:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM info_XboxOne;
```

Con ella te ahorrarías iterar el array.

Espero mi respuesta te ayude, saludos.

Answer (score 0):

ya habían preguntado algo así, puedes revisar la información en  este: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18888716/fatal-error-allowed-memory-size-of-134217728-bytes-exhausted-tried-to-allocate)

Por lo que estaba leyendo necesitar agregar una paginación a tu scrip php para que no te arroje todos los registros completamente, y agregarle un Where a tu consulta para saber que registros mostrar.

Comment: Manuel, añade más información a tu respuesta para poder ayudar a resolver la pregunta: *código*, *ejemplo*.